# Proof: difference in codeword length is less than 2 (Huffman coding of uniform distribution)

Tags: information-theory

Assume an alphabet in which all letters have the same probability. These letters are coded using a binary Huffman code. Proof that the difference in codeword length is less than 2.

It seems intuitively right but I do not know how to prove this formally.

Exact question is:

> A source has an alphabet of $K$ letters, all having the same
>   probability. These are coded using a binary Huffman code. Assume that
>   $K = x \,2^j$, with $j$ integer and $1\le x <2$. Prove that all codewords
>   have lengths $j$ or $j + 1$. Hint: Prove, using the code tree, that
>   the difference in codeword length is less than $2$.

Comment: There is some ambiguity  to build a Huffman code, so a same source can give two different Huffman codes. Are you sure you don't need to prove just that there exists a binary Huffman code such that the difference in codeword length is less than 2?

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a modified version of question 2.14 from "Principles of Digital Communications" (Chapter 2: Coding for Discrete Sources) by Robert Gallager.

> Consider a source with M equiprobable symbols.
>
> (a) Let k = ceil(log M). Show that, for a Huffman code, the only possible codeword lengths are k and k − 1.
>   (b)As a function of M, find how many codewords have
>   length k = ceil(log M). What is the expected codeword length L in
>   bits per source symbol?

Answer (score 1):

I am uploading the solution to 2.14 from the solution manual:

(a) First, we prove that for any equiprobable alphabet, the codeword lengths can diﬀer by at most 1. In the Huﬀman code tree for an equiprobable alphabet, the parent of the branch corresponding to any symbol $j$ has probability at least $2/M$ , which is greater than the probability
of any other symbol $i$. Thus by Lemma 2.5.1, $l_j−1≤l_i$ for every j, i; thus the codeword lengths diﬀer by at most 1.

We have shown that the lengths must be $k$ or $k−1$ for some integer $k$, and it remains to show that $k=⌈\log M⌉$. If M is a power of 2, then all codewords have length $\log M$ and we are done.
Thus assume that $M$ is not a power of 2 and let $n_k$ be the number of codewords with length $k$, where $1 \le n_k \le M−1$). The remaining $M−n$ codewords then have length $k−1$. Since the code is optimal, the code tree is full, and
$$n_k 2^{−k}+(M−n_k) 2^{−(k−1)} =1.$$
Thus
$$2M−n_k=2^k.$$
Since $n_k>0$, it follows that $2M>2^k$ and thus $M>2^{k−1}$. Since $n_k<M$, it follows that
$M<2^k$.Thus $k=⌈\log M⌉$.
(b) From previous equation, $n_k=2M−2^k$. The expected codeword length is then
$$L=\frac{(k−1)(2^k−M)+k(2M−2^k)}{M}=k+1−\frac{2^k}{M}.$$