# How can I design a non-integral-power efficient range coding that is statistically "fair" over the whole range?

Tags: probability, reference-request, soft-question, information-theory

Numbers are represented using binary digits "bits" which are integers in the set $\{0,1\}$.

Positive integers for example, are usually encoded as a sequence of bits so that which power of 2 they encode correspond to the order which they are stored. For example the number $a$ represented by a binary vector $$[b_{N-1},\cdots,b_1,b_0]$$:

$$a = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} b_k \cdot 2^k$$

Now if we know beforehand the range of numbers to be stored, $[0,a_{max}]$. In many cases $a_{max}$ may not be $2^k-1$ for some $k$. In other words... to be able to store any such number we will have to select a number of bits so that a certain set of combination of bits will be unused. From a data compression stand-point, this is unfortunate. Especially bothersome it can be if $a_{max}$ is a small number and we have very many numbers to store.
Take for example $a_{max}$ = 2, this will require us to use $2$ bits, although 1/4 for each such pair of bits of what we can represent will go unused (the number 3 represented by the two bits 11 never occurs).

How can we in this case find a way to compress a set of numbers in the range $\{ 0,\cdots,a_{max} \}$ so that we "on average" (in some sense) don't need more bits than theoretically necessary?

Comment: One way is to encode in blocks: $N$ numbers in $[0:A]$ is the same as one number in $[0:A^N]$, or two numbers in $[0:A^{\lfloor N/2\rfloor}]$ and maybe one left over in $[0,A]$, or three in $[0:A^{\lfloor N/3\rfloor}]$ and a couple left over and so on. Find the blocklength $k_*$ for which $A^{\lfloor N/k\rfloor}$ is closes to a power of two, and encode with that. For variable $N$, you can also just store $N$ and $k_*$ in some fixed data block. Overall you should get quite close to $\log_2 A$ bits per symbol.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 If I understand you right this was my first approach and it works okay up to the limit of my computer built in integer support or so. However it will be dependent on division and modulo arithmetics on the decoder side, and those are not very nice for speed. Especially not if I later on would need to implement long division on big integers.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. But I suppose I then have a question: how much do you value memory over computation? Even if you just encode into $\lceil \log A\rceil$ bits, you have an overhead of only one bit per symbol relative to the optimal $\log A$. As such, these days, memory is usually cheap enough that this isn't that big a deal, and you're usually better off just using this directly - it's faster both for encoding and decoding.

Comment: The Huffman code does buy you something significant, btw. Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331378/proof-difference-in-codeword-length-is-less-than-2-huffman-coding-of-uniform-d/4740734#4740734), you can show that the maximum overhead is about $0.09$ bits per symbol. Going beyond will need some blocking, since Huffman is the optimal single shot code. Of course, if the data has some structure, you can do better. If you don't know what the structure is a priori, then you might be better off just using some universal code like Lempel-Ziv (aka zipping).

Comment: I don't like a full Huffman code solution for this particular problem, my $a_{max}$ can be hundreds if not thousands of bits long. Building and transmitting a full Huffman table would be infeasible. Perhaps if it was done on blocks of the most significant bit in some clever way it would be feasible.

Comment: But if $\log a_\max > 10^2,$ then an overhead of even one bit is sort of meaningless, right? Even if you're storing $10^{10}$ such strings, that's an extra 10GB on a scale of 1TB, which is a few extra bucks. You might even end up paying more for the compute that you'll need to do to save on this cost. (N.B., this is not to suggest that you haven't done a cost-benefit analysis, but more to suggest that describing the results of this, so that we understand the kind of compression-computation tradeoff you care about, will be helpful for the question.)

Comment: Oh, also, for Huffman, since the probabilities are uniform, you don't even need to transmit the code, you just need to transmit $a_{\max}$. You can then build up the tree on the fly at the decoder, given some convention on the order in which symbols are processed. Building it however, would be necessary, which might be too much, but again this becomes a question of how much compute you're willing to sink to save memory.

Comment: I think enough information is carried in the $a_{max}$ and MSB of every number to do entropy coding directly on it. I think I will comb a bit stream of MSBs sorted by the prime bit gap of zeros of a_max. That gap should contain the relevant information of up to log2 precision. No Huffman tables will be needed, just an index vector carrying the sorted bits position and a histogram and it's accumulation.

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable length prefix-free code such as a Huffman code. Some numbers will be assigned to shorter codewords, see below. If the numbers arrive sequentially all you need to do is keep track of how many of them are in the interval $[2^{k-1},a_{max}]$ which gives you an indication of where to go for the $j^{th}$ stored number. The addressing scheme is of course an overhead, there is no free lunch. The example below encodes the interval $[0000,1010]=[0,10].$

[image]

You mentioned probability, if you know which numbers are more frequent then you can map them to shorter codewords, the full-blown version being something like the Huffman code based on a complete probability distribution.